How do I highlight both the middle column and row of a matrix using razor/blazor?
I'm trying to highlight row and col at index [3][3].
However, only the row is being highlighted. Nothing shows for the column.
For ref: This is a c#/blazor program in vs 2022.
Here's the blazor:
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                    <thead class="sticky-top custom-header-style">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="8">EBIT Recovery and Price Simulator</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="highlight">FAB/Yield</th>
                            @for (int j = -3; j <= 3; j++)
                            {
                                <th class="@(j == 0 ? "highlight" : "")">$@Math.Round(FAB + j * FabStep, 2)</th>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for (int i = -3; i <= 3; i++)
                        {
                            <tr class="@(i == 0 ? "highlight" : "")">
                                <td class="@(i == 0 ? "highlight" : "")">@((yield + i * YieldStep).ToString("F2"))%</td>
                                @for (int j = -3; j <= 3; j++)
                                {
                                    <td class="@(i == 0 || j == 0 || (i == 0 && j == 0) ? "highlight" : "")">
                                        $@ebitMatrix[i + 3][j + 3].ToString("F2")
                                    </td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>


css:
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}


Thank you.

This is because ".table-bordered td" already has a background-color:#fff;
make it !important
and it works:
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}


Yep, that did it alright. Thank you, I didn't know about that tag.
